# How to create an installer/.exe/.msi for RCP Product?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to create an RCP application as an exe or msi file. I have exported the application as .product as below.

[image]

But my client wants it as an .exe or .msi file. Answers in stackoverflow suggested to use "EclipseNSIS" to create executable. But EclipseNSIS is not working for Windows 10. Please help me in resolving this issue. The project will not be closed until this issue is resolved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can specify a target platform on which you can create a binary launcher (e.g. a windows 64 bit .exe)... sadly i can't remember any more how it was done....

Comment: there is a minimal explanation about deployment (that is what you are trying to do) on vogella https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#deployment-of-your-application

Comment: if you find the solution can you please add your own answer so that we also learn from your progress...

Comment: Look at [Eclipse Oomph](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/oomph-basic-tutorial/)

Comment: @greg-449 - Thank you for the reference. Can you please provide me the url which shows the process in detail. I tried to install Oomph plugin in my IDE. It seems to be vast and i am not able to find the one which you referred.

Comment: Please post your answer when you find it. We are also stuck with the exact thing.

Comment: I don't know any details about Oomph, just that it does what you are looking for. The 'Oomph Authoring Tooling' and 'Oomph Product Setup Models" sections in the link I give looks like a start.

Comment: [Here is how I do it (creating Windows installer via NSIS in a Maven Tycho build)](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/master/product/pom.xml#L151-L224). If you prefer a `.msi` installer, have a look how [AdoptOpenJDK does it (via WIX Toolset, but for JDK, not for a RCP application)](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-installer).